# Applications think that GPS is off while it is on

Tags: applications, gps, prestigio-multipad

I have a Prestigio Multiphone 3400 with Android 4.2.2. The phone is new and not rooted.

In Settings -> Personal -> Location Access, there are two checkboxes:

1. Access to my location
2. Wi-Fi & mobile network location

Both of them are checked.

But the only application with working GPS is Google Maps.

I tried for example [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) and [GPS Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mictale.gpsessentials), but they both show GPS is off / GPS is currently disabled.

In the Settings -> Device -> Apps -> (application name) there is "This app can access the following on your phone:" followed with "approximate location (network-based)" and "precise location (GPS and network-based)"

Why are the Google Maps special? And why other apps cannot use GPS, while the permissions are obviously granted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The specs for the device](http://www.gsmarena.com/stats.php3/prestigio_multiphone_3400_duo-5888.php) state it does not have GPS.

> GPS: No

Google maps is using 'best location source' for you which is Network / WiFi signal on your device. If you have all of them turned on it will revert to the most accureate one it can find, which are in the order `Network > WiFi > GPS` generally. Basically Google Maps isn't using GPS for you, it just isn't giving you an error message.

[The Prestigio site](http://www.prestigio.com/catalogue/MultiPhones/MultiPhone_3400_DUO#/product-specs?article=PAP3400DUO) doesn't mention GPS at all.

[This link isn't in English but mentions No GPS in several reviews.](http://androidforum.cz/prestigio-multiphone-3400-duo-4-dc-1-2ghz-1500mah-t47860.html)

e.g.

> Trocha ma štve GPS,ktorý telefon nema
>
> It annoys me the phone has no GPS.

Another quick translate turned this up:

> I was disappointed inability to run the GPS. Neither the manufacturer's website is not clearly stated whether the GPS is present or not. Due to the navigation application on the phone, I assumed that it will run. Unfortunately, the opposite is true. I would therefore asked how the GPS is really whether it is hardware GPS device in the phone is present and could be a problem installing the software and possibly what. thank you

Comment: Wow, I thought all phones would have GPS by default nowadays... e-shops should warn for ones that does not have it.

Comment: BTW that link is in my native language :)

Comment: Yeah there is an assumption that you have Bluetooth, WiFi and GPS as standard additions to a smart device, the manufacturer really dodged even mentioning GPS on their site! Glad the link helped, I was relying on translate for it! Happy coincedence you speak Czech! :)